# Geodesically complete spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, topology, geodesics

By definition, a spacetime is geodesically complete if all inextendible curve are complete but  is this equivalent to «if all geodesic of finite length has endpoints»?

My situation is:
I have a set of null geodesics, they all have a past end point on the same surface, (they are converging because it’s a trapped surface) and thus encounter a caustic. Does geodesic completeness implies that they have a future endpoint?